# Azure Data Warehouse Query Length Limits or Where Clause Limits

Tags: python, sql, azure

I have a dataset which is about 10GBs held on an Azure Data Warehouse. All of this data is contained within a single table. I need to pull a ton of different subsets from this table based on various locations, time frames, and ids. Effectively the query would look something akin to:

```
select * from table 
where (id = '93210912' and date <= '2020-04-01' and date >= '2020-01-01' and location = 'Location1') 
   or (id = '93210912' and date <= '2020-03-01' and date >= '2020-02-01' and location = 'Location2') 
   or (id = '23524234' and date <= '2020-06-01' and date >= '2020-03-01' and location = 'Location1')
   or ...
```

However, I would have roughly 100,000 `where` clause `or` statements like the above which are being created programmatically. Initially I didn't think there would need to be this many `where` clauses and that it would be more efficient to offload most of the work onto the Database. However, with how many where clauses there are now I am concerned if there is a max query length or a max number of where clause  or statements that Azure Data Warehouse can handle.

Is this not a big deal? Should I make a slew of smaller queries and ask for them individually? Is there a more recommended approach? Should I move the full dataset to the compute environment and manage the sub-setting with python and pandas? **What are best practices in this situation?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is OK. I used to create a test to see the maximum length supported by sql.

Execute the following sql script:

```sql
select * from table where id in (character)
```

10,000 Guid strings, passed in the query analyzer, OK, it seems to support 320,000 length (320K).

Add another order of magnitude to 100,000, which is OK! Support 3.2M length.

Add an order of magnitude to 1 million, which is OK! ! Support 32M length, but it is too slow, sql executes for 5 minutes before returning the result.

Add an order of magnitude to 10 million, which is OK! ! ! Support 320M length, it took 1 hour and 3 minutes to return the result.

Anyway, I think the total character length is 320 million, 320M.

The conclusion is that you can use it with confidence, 320 million bytes is greater than your estimate.